# Use Excel VBA to find column matches & merge based on the values of two other column

Tags: vba, excel, consolidation

I have a little conundrum here & while there's a few suggestions on the site, there's nothing that quite fits the bill for me. I need to merge some rows based on the values of some cells in the row.

I guess I need some sort of code that matches the name then searches for a 'New Starter' entry with that same name.

Here's how my data (Shift, name, detail) looks:

```
09:00-17:00 Smith John      Present
09:00-11:00 Smith John      New Starter
11:10-13:00 Smith John      New Starter
14:00-17:00 Smith John      New Starter
09:00-17:00 Connor Sarah    Present
09:00-11:00 Connor Sarah    New Starter
11:10-13:00 Connor Sarah    New Starter
14:00-17:00 Connor Sarah    New Starter
09:00-17:00 Claus Santa     Present
10:00-18:00 Mouse Mickey    Present
10:00-11:00 Mouse Mickey    New Starter
11:10-13:00 Mouse Mickey    New Starter
14:00-18:00 Mouse Mickey    New Starter
```

I need to remove the New Starter lines (If they exist) but also replace their 'Present' cell with 'New Starter' (Although this can be different text if needed):

```
09:00-17:00 Smith John      New Starter
09:00-17:00 Connor Sarah    New Starter
09:00-17:00 Claus Santa     Present
10:00-18:00 Mouse Mickey    New Starter
```

You can see here that Santa is not a New Starter & therefore stays as 'Present'.

Essentially, the 'New Starter' lines are not needed, but I do want to give new starters a different detail to the present staff.

Additional notes:

- A 'Present' line will always exist if a 'New Starter' exists. If they have a 'Day Off', there'll just be a 'Day Off' line which I've already included in other Subs to extract.
- The data to keep is whatever is in the "Present" line, only replacing that title (Column C).

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  This is doable, but Stack Overflow is not a code outsourcing platform.  Share what you have tried and where you are stuck before asking for help. ([See Help for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any actual code that I've used. Examples I've found online elsewhere talk about merging data to a single cell (i.e. Concatenate). Other examples refer to pulling data from separate sheets & combining it into a single sheet... I've not tried using these as they'd most likely take a large amount of re-engineering since they don't start off with the same situation I have... My apologies for not explaining the data to keep clearly. The data to keep is whatever is in the "Present" line, only replacing that title (Column C).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Christmas007. I've been on this project for about 3 days solid now so I'm going to focus on the areas I'm fine with. If I need to provide some example code, I'll come back to this. I have a deadline with bosses & since I can work with not doing the above, this will fall into the "Nice to haves" category. Once I reach the deadline & they're happy with what I've created so far, I can then work on day 2 improvements later.

Comment: That's correct, a 'Present' line will always exist if a 'New Starter' exists. If they have a 'Day Off', there'll just be a 'Day Off' line which I've already included in other Subs to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should address your conditions. Tested Working.

```
Sub RemoveDups()

Dim CurRow As Long, LastRow As Long, SrchRng As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A1:C" & LastRow).Select
    Sheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    Sheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & LastRow) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With Sheets(1).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

For CurRow = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("C" & CurRow).Value = "Present" Then
        If CurRow <> 2 Then
            If Not Range("B2:B" & CurRow - 1).Find(Range("B" & CurRow).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) is Nothing Then
                Range("C" & CurRow).Value = "New Starter"
            End If
        End If
    ElseIf Range("C" & CurRow).Value = "New Starter" Then
        Range("C" & CurRow).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End If
Next CurRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Christmas007, thank you for taking the time to build this for me. It's currently changing all 'Present' entries to 'New Starter', but it'll give me something to get my teeth into tomorrow. I'll let you know how things go & share anything I discover. Thanks again.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for taking a look at my problem. I've had to make a couple of small tweaks because I do have more than just 'Present' & 'New Starter' in my data. Should I just edit what you have posted above to show my adjustments?

Answer (score 1):

A second method for you to consider, perhaps a bit more 'generic' and 'portable' in terms of the location of your data.  If you want to sort the data before consolidating, then this uses the alternative (more  long-standing?) `Range.Sort` method compatible back to Excel 2003.  Further parameters to refine this method can be found in the [msdn reference, here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
Option Explicit
Sub newStarters()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim dRng As Range
Dim stRow As Long, endRow As Long, nameCol As Long, c As Long
Dim nme As String, changeStr As String

'explicitly identify data sheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
'start row of data
stRow = 2
'column number of "Name"
nameCol = 3
'set changeStr
changeStr = "New Starter"

    'Use the explicit data sheet
    With ws
        'find last data row
        endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, nameCol).End(xlUp).Row

        'if you want the data to be sorted before consolidating
        '======================================================
        'Set dRng = .Range(.Cells(stRow, nameCol).Offset(0, -1), _
        '            .Cells(endRow, nameCol).Offset(0, 1))

        'dRng.Sort Key1:=.Cells(stRow, nameCol), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        '          Key2:=.Cells(stRow, nameCol).Offset(0, 1), Order2:=xlDescending, _
        '          Header:=xlNo
        '======================================================
            'consolidate data
            For c = endRow To stRow Step -1
                With .Cells(c, nameCol)
                    nme = .Value
                        If .Offset(0, 1).Value = changeStr Then
                            If .Offset(-1, 0).Value = nme Then
                                .Offset(-1, 1).Value = changeStr
                                .EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
                            End If
                        End If
                End With
            Next c
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The code from Christmas007 is working for me, however I do like the idea of being more 'generic' and 'portable'. I'll duplicate my project & take a look at this option too.